# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException caused by substring

Tags: android, string, substring

I received this crash report in my Google Play Console which I myself never experience.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2505)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2577)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1462)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:964)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:759)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
  at java.lang.String.startEndAndLength (String.java:504)
  at java.lang.String.substring (String.java:1333)
  at .Word.onCreate (Word.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6093)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1106)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2458)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2577)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000 (ActivityThread.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1462)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:160)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5541)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:964)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

This crash report doesn't mention which line of my `Word.java` class is causing the problem. In my class, I use the following `substring` method.

```
definition = defn.substring(0, defn.indexOf("@"));
sentence = rawMeaning.substring(rawMeaning.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
```

Examples of my `defn` string are `test1@test2`, `test1@`. Every of my `defn` string string contains `@`. Some string contains character after `@`, some do not contains any character after `@`. My `rawMeaning` string share a similar format with my `defn` string.

It is interesting that I received another crash report which give me similar error but it mentioned the error is caused my in app billing, [StringIndexOutOfBoundsException caused by in app billing queryInventoryAsync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684499/stringindexoutofboundsexception-caused-by-in-app-billing-queryinventoryasync)

How to solve this?

Comment: you want to have values for strings before and after 
"@" right?

Comment: test1@test2, test1@ : these two will be the cases? no other case like test1@test2@test3 ?

Comment: Nope, there will only one, single `@`

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely 100% sure that all of your strings contain the "@" character?  As you have not shown this to be the case, that still remains the most likely cause.  In fact, with the code you have shown, the *only* possible explanation is that your code is processing a string *without* this character.

I suggest releasing a new version of your app that will provide diagnostic information in the event of this error.  Try this:

Change

```
definition = defn.substring(0, defn.indexOf("@"));
```

To

```
 try {
    definition = defn.substring(0, defn.indexOf("@"));
 } catch (Exception ex) {
    String message = "Error processing string: (" + defn + ")";
    throw new RuntimeException(message, ex);
 }
```

Then the next time the app crashes, the crash log will contain a stack trace with a message telling you what string caused the problem.

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure all of my string contains `@`. I will apply your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: If you are 100% sure, then the exception cannot be from the one line of code that you posted.  You should post all of the `Word.onCreate` method so that we can see all of your calls to `substring`.

Comment: That are all my calls to `substring`. Possible source of the crash is in app billing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684499/stringindexoutofboundsexception-caused-by-in-app-billing-queryinventoryasync

Comment: and that stack trace shows the same thing that this one does.  On line 299 or Word.java, `substring` is being called.  Is Word.java your class?  Did you write it?  From your question, it is unclear where your one-line of code comes from.  Is it Word.java.  Please clarify.

Comment: The crash report only state ` at .Word.onCreate (Word.java)` and no not mention where is the line. I swear.

Comment: 1) If that is the case, why have you not posted the entire contents of Word.java - or at least the onCreate method?  2) The other question you posted did give a line number of 299.  3) I am still waiting for you to answer my questions above about Word.java.  You still have not told us if it is your class or not.  Please read and answer my questions.

Comment: In this question itself, I have mentioned `Word.java` is my class. Please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

> **If you are sure about getting max of two words as a result, try opting for "split" rather then finding a "subString".**

**Your Code:**

```
definition = defn.substring(0, defn.indexOf("@"));
sentence = rawMeaning.substring(rawMeaning.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
```

**Try With:**

```
String[] words = defn.split("@);
definition =words[0];
sentence = words.length>1? words[1] : "";
```

Comment: I know this. But the thing is my `defn` and `rawMeaning` are different. So `split` is not suitable in my case.

Comment: then there is only way that you surround your code with try/catch as there is other answer mentioned already I am respecting it and not making a duplicate answer here